# changing the notification ringtone in android

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone

I have implemented `preference screen` on own i.e., I have prepared `custom listview` and managed all the things what my app needs on own. But I am stuck how to give user a facility to change the notification ringtone. Usually we can achieve this by `RingtonePreferece`.

But how to implement it without using preference screen, so that by clicking on that list item it should redirect the user to list of ringtones and when he selects that particular ringtone, the title of the ringtone should be shown on that particular list row and has to be used as ringtone for notification. Can someone please suggest on how to achieve this? Below is my notification code.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)  
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker(msg)
                .setContentTitle(title)  
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true);
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
         manager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok the first step would be to allow the user to select the ringtone he wants. I will help you implement an activity that lists the available ringtones and allows the user to select one. Naturally, this activity is a ListActivity.

First of all create a container for the ringtone. I called it RingtoneObject and it contains the name of the ringtone along with the uri of the ringtone:

```
private static final class RingtoneObject {
    private String name;
    private Uri uri;
    public RingtoneObject(String name, Uri uri) {
        this.name = name;
        this.uri = uri;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name==null?"":name.toString();
    }

}
```

In the onCreate, you should query the RingtoneManager for the available ringtones and then iterate over them and add them to the list of type RingtoneObject. The code for this is simply:

```
ArrayAdapter<RingtoneObject> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RingtoneManager ringtoneMgr = new RingtoneManager(this);
    ringtoneMgr.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    Cursor alarmsCursor = ringtoneMgr.getCursor();
    int alarmsCount = alarmsCursor.getCount();
    RingtoneObject[] alarms = new RingtoneObject[alarmsCount];
    int index = 0;
    while(alarmsCursor.moveToNext()) {
        alarms[index] = new RingtoneObject(ringtoneMgr.getRingtone(index).getTitle(this), ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(index));
        index++;
    }
    alarmsCursor.close();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MainActivity.RingtoneObject>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alarms);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

You can notice that the adapter's scope is out of the onCreate function. I need reference to it in the OnItemClickListener's callback. You can, as well, notice that I set the OnItemClickListener of the listview to **this** which is, in this context, the activity itself. Therefore the activity should implement `OnItemClickListener` and when an item is clicked: I simply played the ringtone.

```
MediaPlayer md;
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(md != null) {
        if(md.isPlaying())
            md.stop();
        md = null;
    }
    md = MediaPlayer.create(this, adapter.getItem(position).uri);
    md.start();
}
```

Again, the `MediaPlayer` is out of the function because I need the reference whenever I want to stop playing.

Anyway, in your own onItemClick function or some other sort of mechanism you present for the user to select a ringtone, you will have to save the Uri of the ringtone in some persistent storage (e.g. SharedPreferences) and then when you want to show the notification, use the saved uri.

Note: You can save the uri as a string using `theUri.toString()` and load this string and convert it back to a Uri using `Uri.parse(theString)`.

[Here is the complete sample (for uri selection).](http://www.mediafire.com/download/822xv2d4111zl90/ringtone.zip)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  How to get single choice mode for this listview so that user can select? I tried with getListView().setSingleChoicemode(...); it didn't work. Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I figured it out.BTW it takes lot of time to retrieve the ringtones. Of course I ran it in background thread, but it takes time.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that let you set tone:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);

//custom sound
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.siren);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew this. Your code sets the ringtone which is in the raw folder, but I need to show list of ringtones present in the device just like ringtone preferences does.

Comment: Create a list in Which user can select ringtone. You put name of em

Comment: Yeah, but do I need to prepare the list again? Or is there any provider so that I can access them directly in the list just like contacts list without doing any extra work?